# Flex 4: Binding Label To Dataprovider (SQLite)

Tags: sql, apache-flex

Let me start off by saying this is my first Flex project, so I've been reading a lot, learning a lot, but am still struggling to make this work.

I am trying to display records from an SQLite database within my Flex mobile application. I have the input form saving data correctly to the database, and I have a datagrid that is outputting the records (so I can confirm everything looks good). However, my problem is making the data readable.

I want the user to be able to select an identifier from either a drop down or a list (even if it's just a 1 column datagrid), and have the labels to the right update to reflect that information.

My thought was to have the datagrid setup as such:

```
    <mx:DataGrid x="10" y="10" width="100" height="500" id="SiteSelector" dataProvider="{siteData}" includeIn="SiteDetails" change="SiteChoice(event)">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Site Name" dataField="SiteName" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

The datagrid shows the Site Name without issue from the database.  The change function:

```
            private function SiteChoice(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = connection;
            statement.text = "SELECT * FROM SITES WHERE SITE_ID = ?"
            statement.parameters[0] = SiteSelector.selectedItem.SITE_ID;
            statement.execute();
            siteDetails.source = statement.getResult().data;
        }
```

I also have declared:

```
[Bindable] private var siteDetails:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

My question is, how do I get a label to reflect specific column data from the table?  I believe I plug it with the siteDetails as the data provider, but how do I specify that I want, say for instance, the address or site contact to appear in a label?

```
<s:Label text="{siteDetails}" id="ExternalIPLBL"/>
```

I've been searching Google and the Adobe Developer Connection/livedocs/cookbooks pretty heavily over the last week and still have yet to come up with a working solution.

Comment: Since siteDetails is an ArrayCollection, do you mean you want the label to be repeated with each instance showing an entry's field within that ArrayCollection?

Comment: I agree with @Frank's answer. Also, you should'nt use an ArrayCollection as a dataProvider for a label. You would use an ArrayCollection as a dataprovider for a list type item. Once you get your results, step through the siteDetails AC, and then set the labels text values based on the siteDetails values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
first, you can display a field form an arraycollectiokn like this

```
siteDetails.getItemAt(0).Street}
```

The dynamic is the getItemAt(0) Value. Register an clickhandler to the datagrid and debug the event. Somewhere there, the selectedIndex is a part of that event.

By the way, id should start with small letters ->ExternalIPLBL

Set an Breakpoint in the eventhandler, try to find out, where your data are (selectedIndex) and set the label text in the eventhandler:
ExternalIPLBL.text = event.selectedIndex[Street].

BR
Frank